# Error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: javascript, syntax-error

I'm making a simple blackjack game in Javascript, but when I try to run it, it gives me that error. Specifically, Chrome tells me that the error is on this line:

```
if y <= 17
```

Here's all my code:

```
var x = null;
var y = null;
var numsDeal = new Array();
for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    nDeal = Math.floor(Math.random()*(11-1)+1)+1;
    numsDeal[i] = nDeal;
    y = numsDeal[0]+numsDeal[1];
}



var nums = new Array();
for (i=0;i<2;i++){
    n = Math.floor(Math.random()*(11-1)+1)+1;
    nums[i] = n;
    x = nums[0]+nums[1];
}

function hit(){
hitC = Math.floor(Math.random()*(11-1)+1)+1;
x = x + hitC;
    if y <= 17
        hitD = Math.floor(Math.random()*(11-1)+1)+1;
        y = y + hitD
        y.toString();
        document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = y;
x.toString();
document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
}

x.toString();

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
```

As you can see, y is declared. Can anyone help me? I'm sure I'm being stupid.

By the way, I have searched for solutions, but I both can't understand them as I'm a beginner, and I don't think they're the same as my problem. I hope to be proven wrong.

Comment: really?? Where on earth are the brackets?

Comment: What language was this supposed to be again? Better read up on the `if` statement.

Comment: This code is just...

Comment: BTW  `y.toString();` is a noop.

Comment: I understand it's bad, I literally started programming today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should listen to your browser...

```
if ( y <= 17 ) {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: I seriously doubt the pedagogical efficacy of encouraging people to post trivial syntax errors to SO. This is not a scalable way for them to learn how to program. Nor does it help anyone else in the future. Our answers should be about how to **think** about the problem, how to track it down, and what kinds of resources to consult.

Answer (score 0):

Where you have:

```
    if y <= 17
    ...
```

it should be:

```
if(y <= 1) {
// code here...
}
```